# Python edit email xlsx attachment without downloading the file

Tags: python, email-attachments

I'm trying to walk through email messages and edit xlsx attachments
to unhide hidden sheets. 
The problem is that I can't download the files using imaplib package since it is not possible to save the files on my workspace, so I'm looking for a workaround to edit the sheets status without downloading the attachments.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you imaging to edit the content of a file without downloading, even in you memory?

Comment: I was thinking of an access to the attachment content without the download part @stovfl

Comment: Thats not possible, even you have access to the mailbox store on the mailserver. Your script have to run on the mailserver, are you allowed to run a script on the mailserver?